# Inner Join query between 2 tables with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

We have 2 tables `Application` and `Address`, Application table has columns like home_address,office_address and delivery_address and all these 3 column is of number type having values like say 111,112 and 113 for a row of it.It has many such rows. In a separate table we have say column like id and address having lot of records with different id's. we need to get output like say all above 3 columns plus 3 more columns like say full_homeaddress, full_officeaddress , full_deliveryaddress in every row of output.

If it was only one column like home_address in Application table, i would have easily done the join with primary key of Address table and one foreign key of Application table but here we need to display full address of 3 different fields simultaneosly in each row of output.

I think for one row of output, i will have to get records from 1 row of Application table and 3 different rows of Address table to display in every row of output. For these 3 columns of Application table , required addresses are in 3 different rows of Address table.

Kindly help how to write join for it

Comment: That's rather hard to follow - e.g. " Primary key of Address table are foreign keys for the 3 addresses". Can you post the table definitions please?

Comment: Two tables. One references another via foreign key constraint. You want to join those tables. What's stopping you? Join them on those columns, e.g. `address.pk_column = application.foreign_key_column`

Comment: @Tony Andrews   Application table has columns like home_address,office_address and delivery_address and all these 3 column is of number type having values like say 111,112 and 113 for a row of it.It has many such rows. In a separate table we have say column like id and address having lot of records with different id's. we need to get output like say all above 3 columns plus 3 more columns like say full_homeaddress, full_officeaddress , full_deliveryaddress in every row of output..

Comment: I have edited the main description for this question, Please have a look there as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT app.*,
   home.address_description,
   office.address_description,
   delivery.address_description
FROM application app,
   Address home,
   Address office,
   Address delivery
WHERE 
   app.homeaddressId = home.addressId(+)
   AND app.officeAddressId = office.addressId(+)
   AND app.deliveryAddressId = delivery.addressId(+)
```

Comment: As far as I know, it is recommended to use the ANSI join syntax rather than Oracle's original _(+)_ syntax.

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator for outer joins